# Generate pay stub with vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a sheet that has one employee with pay information, including tax deductions, and I want to have a button that, when clicked, automatically generates a pay stub with all relevant information for a given week.

I'm able to generate a new sheet in the desired format, but I have trouble getting data from one sheet to another. I need, for instance, the `row` of `1/10/16` to populate into predetermined cells.

[This is a sample of the worksheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Te2WZjN-FkUTFrN05vX2dDTG8/view?usp=sharing) I am working with.

Comment: Thanks @Mykola for editing my question. This is the first coding question I've ever posted :)

Comment: @Mykola: Its ok, np)))

Answer (score 1):

This is it!!! ...but I was wondering if there was a way or reason to shorten it?
And as I need 52 of these for each week, is there a better way other than making one macro for each week?

```
Sub JanuaryThird()


Dim strFilename As String
Dim dir As String

strFilename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A3").Text
dir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pay Stubs\"


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Open Pay Stub Template
    Workbooks.Open filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PayStubTemplate.xlsx"


'Copy Name
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Name
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


'Copy Hours Worked
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Hours Worked
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("D4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


'Copy Pay Rate
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Pay Rate
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


'Copy Period End
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Period End
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("H4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


'Copy Check No.
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Check No.
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("J4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


'Copy Base YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Base YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("E7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Overtime YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("H3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Overtime YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("E7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Federal W/H
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Federal W/H
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("I7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Federal W/H YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("M3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Federal W/H YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("K7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy SS YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("O3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste SS YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("K8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Medicare YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("Q3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Medicare YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("K9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy L&I YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("S3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste L&I YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("K10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Gross Earnings YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("J3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Gross Earnings YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("E14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy Net Earnings YTD
    Windows("Pay Summary 2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("W3").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Paste Net Earnings YTD
    Windows("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("PayStub").Select
    Range("E15").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Save as PDF
    Workbooks("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=dir & strFilename, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


'Close Template
    Workbooks("PaystubTemplate.xlsx").Close False


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok so first things first, I'm assuming you have the Developer ribbon all set up.  Here is the quick and easy Macro I did for testing.  THIS CODE DOESN'T ACCOUNT FOR A DATE THAT DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST IN THE LIST, SO YOU'LL HAVE TO ADD THAT IN IF YOU THINK IT WILL BE A PROBLEM.  I used a space in the sheet to be the "input" for the date we want to select (screen shot attached and make sure that cell is formatted the same as your date range), by changing this date, it will change the line that gets copied.  The initial Range you set will be the first line with a date (according to your example this would be "A6"), and currRow is that row number (so 6).  Also, the line below the If statement is choosing a range to copy over, if it's always going to be A to U then this is fine, if not you can edit the "U".  Under that I have the name of the worksheet ("Sheet2") that you want to paste to, along with the cell ("A1") I want to paste to.

```
Sub CopyOver()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
currRow = 2

Do While True

    If Selection.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value Then
        Range("A" & currRow & ":" & "U" & currRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Do
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        currRow = currRow + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

After you get your macro written, create the button by going to Developer->Insert->Button(Form Control).  Then you can Assign the name of the macro to it in the pop-up (This one is called "CopyOver").  You can then rename the button anything you want by selecting the text on it.  Hope this helped!

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcxTc.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70PTM.png)

Comment: This code wont populate specific cells just an entire row... The form control button suggestion was extremely helpful though as 52 ActiveX buttons aren't a good idea which I found out the long way :)